# Помогите спарсить новостной сайт

Tags: python, парсер

Решил сделать парсинг сайта новостного, что бы в будущем сделать телеграм бота, это не важно, в общем, написал код, запускаю, а он не срабатывает, пишет вот это:

```
PowerChell 7.2.1.
copyright (c) microsoft corporation.
ссылка на сайт
Type 'help' to get help.
PS путь к расположению питона
```

делал все по инструкции с ютуба, код приложу ниже, помогите пожалуйстаааа.....

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time

def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36"
    }
 
    url = "https://novosti-n.org/"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    newsLists_links = soup.find_all("a", class_="newsList_link ")

    for newsList in newsLists_links:
        newsList_title = newsList.find("div", class_="newsList_item ddd hentry").text.strip()
        newsList_desc = newsList.find("span").text.strip()
        newsList_url = f'https://novosti-n.org/{newsList.get("href")}'
        newsList_date_time = newsList.find("time").get("datetime")

        newsList_date_time = newsList.find("time").get("datetime")
        date_from_iso = datetime.fromisoformat(newsList_date_time)
        date_time = datetime.strftime(date_from_iso, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        newsList_date_timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
        print(f"{newsList_title} | {newsList_url} | {newsList_date_timestamp}")



get_first_news()
```

Comment: newsLists_links выдает пустой список, поэтому результат нулевой.

Comment: а сайт рабочий?)

Comment: @Дима Виноградов рабочий)

Comment: @Сергей Шашко а как это исправить...? У мужичка все так было...

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам фрагмент кода, разберайтесь:

```
newsLists_links = soup.find("div", class_="tabsContent__item is-active js-tabsContent").find_all("div", class_="newsList__item ddd hentry")

    for newsList in newsLists_links:
        newsList_title = newsList.find("div", class_="newsList__right").text.strip()
        print(newsList_title)
        newsList_url = f'https://novosti-n.org/{newsList.find("a").get("href")}'
        print(newsList_url)
        newsList_date_time = newsList.find("abbr").get("title")
        print(newsList_date_time)
```

Comment: супер, спасибо огромное за помощь